# How to make a function in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I'm making a function in Oracle but it gives me error and I don't know why

here is the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_increment_salary15 (psueldo number)
return number 
IS
    v_ventas number;
    valorretornado number;
BEGIN 
    v_ventas:=0;
    valorretornado:=0;
    SELECT ee.nombre, COUNT(ve.IdEmpleado) INTO v_ventas FROM empleado ee INNER JOIN
    venta ve ON ee.idempleado = ve.idempleado 
    GROUP BY ee.nombre;
    IF v_ventas > 500 THEN
        valorretornado := psueldo + (psueldo * 0.15);
    ELSE valorretornado := psueldo + (psueldo * 0);
    END IF;
    return valorretornado;
END;
/
```

and here is the error

```
ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

Comment: You select two columns, into one variable.

Comment: You are also probably, from the joins and grouping and lack of filter, getting multiple rows and trying to fit them all into a scalar variable. If there are multiple `ee.nombre` values, which one's count is supposed to drive your logic? It isn't really clear what you overall aim is...

Comment: so i need to define more variables when i call more columns?

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting ee.nombre, COUNT(ve.IdEmpleado) 
but assigning it to only 1 variable

try below

```
 SELECT ee.nombre, COUNT(ve.IdEmpleado) INTO v_ventas,valorretornado FROM empleado ee INNER JOIN
    venta ve ON ee.idempleado = ve.idempleado 
    GROUP BY ee.nombre;
```

Comment: But it won't take valorretornado a the value of COUNT(ve.IdEmpleado) too?

Comment: PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values  , error come because you select 2 and assign to 1;. What is your new error?

Comment: Ohh ok i understand, so i need to define another variable for ee.nombre right?

Comment: yes.. you need to define. and after into you can give that new variable as shown in my answer

Answer (score 0):

One other comment: you are doing a SELECT INTO with a GROUP BY which implies you expect more than one possible value for ee.nombre.  If that is the case then you will experience a too_many_rows exception: you cannot select multiple rows into a single variable.

If you are instead just looking for the total count of rows then you can remove ee.nombre from the SELECT and remove the GROUP BY entirely.

```
SELECT COUNT(ve.idempleado)
  INTO v_ventas
  FROM empleado ee
 INNER JOIN venta ve
    ON ee.idempleado = ve.idempleado;
```

If you are only interested in ee.nombre values where the count is > 500 you can look at the HAVING clause, but in this scenario you would have the GROUP BY and thus would need to handle multiple rows.

```
SELECT ee.nombre,
       COUNT(ve.idempleado)
  FROM empleado ee
 INNER JOIN venta ve
    ON ee.idempleado = ve.idempleado
 GROUP BY ee.nombre
HAVING COUNT(ve.idempleado) > 500;
```

It seems that maybe you intended to pass in another parameter?  Perhaps you want to count ve.idempleado for a single ee.nombre?

```
SELECT COUNT(ve.idempleado)
  INTO v_ventas
  FROM empleado ee
 INNER JOIN venta ve
    ON ee.idempleado = ve.idempleado
 WHERE ee.nombre = :something;
```